How to calculate the conductor of Dirichlet character associated to a Galois representation?
I am reading Serre's 1972 paper - in section 5.6, he considers an $\ell$-adic representation $\rho_{\ell}(G)$ to lie in a Borel subgroup (i.e., upper triangular matrices). He then says there ought to be two corresponding characters
$$\chi_1, \chi_2: G \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{\ell}^{\times}$$
which by class field theory can be identified by Dirichlet characters
$$\chi_1:(\mathbb{Z}/f_1 \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{\ell}^{\times}$$
$$ \chi_2:(\mathbb{Z}/f_2 \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{\ell}^{\times}$$ where $f_1,f_2$ are conductors of $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$.
Could someone explain to me how to compute these characters and their conductors? From this question I understand why such characters exist, but I still do not see how to compute them. Maybe an example would be enlightening. Thank you so much!
